# SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Tags: java, apache-poi, wildfly

I have two servers running a Java Application 1.8 and JAX-RS in 3 instances (total 6 instances between 2 servers), each instance have a Wildfly 24 Server but I have an error when I try to generate an xlsx file `application/vnd.ms-excel`, in the first instance of the first server this works, but if I try in another one of the same instance I have the following error:

```
2023-08-17 16:11:24,351 INFO  [cl.test.services.rest.ReportRS] (default task-5) [start method] getControlReport
2023-08-17 16:11:26,772 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
2023-08-17 16:11:26,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)         at deployment.srv-reports.ear//org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createAndRegisterSXSSFSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:705)
2023-08-17 16:11:26,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)         at deployment.srv-reports.ear//org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:722)
2023-08-17 16:11:26,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)         at deployment.srv-reports.ear.srv-reports-ejb.jar//cl.test.ejb.pattern.bo.ReportBO.getControlReport(ReportBO.java:830)
2023-08-17 16:11:26,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)         at deployment.reports.ear.srv-reports-ejb.jar//cl.test.ejb.session.stateless.facade.ReportsFacade.getControlReport(ReportsFacade.java:175)
2023-08-17 16:11:26,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2023-08-17 16:11:26,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2023-08-17 16:11:26,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2023-08-17 16:11:26,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

This is an example how to work now:

Server 1:

- Instance 1: Works
- Instance 2: Permission denied
- Instance 3: Permission denied

Server 2:

- Instance 1: Permission denied
- Instance 2: Works
- Instance 3: Permission denied

Each instance of servers was created with the same Wildfly configuration and JDK

I tried to generate an XLSX with JAX-RS and `@Produces({"application/vnd.ms-excel"})` but just works in 1 instance of each server. I want to this works in each instance.

Comment: I would assume the user doesn't have access to write to the file system or the specific file. However, the stack trace is cut off so it's just a guess.

Comment: The simpler explanation is that the three instances have three different users and only one of those users has the rights to the relevant folder/file. The issue is independent from the Java code.